# How to add a parameter at the end of a restFul service URL?

Tags: java, xml, json, rest

I am trying to add a parameter at the end of the restFul web service URL.

**USING Spring3**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchForXmlFormat/{lastName}*?format=xml"* ,headers="Accept=application/atom+xml",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

I want to get something like this:

```
rest/name/abcd?format=xml
```

or

```
rest/name/abcd?format=json.
```

I have the codes to get the data in JSON /XML format. I need to figure out how to add the `?format=xml`  or `?format=json` at the end.

Comment: that @RequestMapping suggest to me that you're using some specific framework ... can we know which one ?

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't the recipient of your request just check what data format you're accepting from your request headers?

Otherwise, I guess you could specify them as query parameters, but this is totally dependant on what language and frameworks you're using.

Comment: Have the "format?=xml or format?=json" is a requirement for my project. Otherwise I would not do that.

Comment: Your query parameter is built wrong anyway. It should be **?format=json**, with the question mark at the end of your uri.

Comment: Ok you should mention that in the question, I have no idea what that even is.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JAX-RS, I think what you're looking for is the annotation [`QueryParam`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html). Here's an example that may fit your case:

```
@GET
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
public String doGet(@QueryParam("format") String fmt) {
//...
}
```

With the code above the `fmt` will contain the value of the parameter `format` in your URL `rest/name/abcd?format=...`

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/lastName/{lastName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody String searchLdapUsersByLastName(@QueryParam("format") @PathVariable("lastName") String lastName) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
 ...}